# How to use parameterized IN cluase in cosmos with QueryDefinition?

Tags: c#, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi, asp.net-core-6.0

I have a query which works when I create as a string but when I use `QueryDefinition` and pass it as parameter, `IN` clause doesn't work.

How to fix that?

Here, `allStockNumbers` will be `"11", "22"` and `filters?.LineItemState` will be `"someString"`

Working:

```
 var allStockNumbers = string.Join(", ", stockNumbers.Select(x => "\"" + x + "\""));
 var query = !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(filters?.LineItemState)
    ? $"SELECT f.id, f.location, f.stockNumber, f.vin, f.totalCarliCost, f.totalCostSubmitted, f.createdDateTime, f.createdBy, f.earliestPaymentDate, f.paymentItems, ARRAY(SELECT * FROM c IN f.lineItems where c.itemState = {"\"" + filters.LineItemState + "\"" }) as lineItems FROM f WHERE f.stockNumber IN ({allStockNumbers})"
    : $"SELECT f.id, f.location, f.stockNumber, f.vin, f.totalCarliCost, f.totalCostSubmitted, f.createdDateTime, f.createdBy, f.earliestPaymentDate, f.paymentItems, f.lineItems FROM f WHERE f.stockNumber IN ({allStockNumbers})";
```

Not Working:

```
var allStockNumbers = string.Join(", ", stockNumbers.Select(x => "\"" + x + "\""));
QueryDefinition query;
if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(filters?.LineItemState))
{
    var lineItemState = "\"" + filters.LineItemState + "\"";
    query = new QueryDefinition(
            @"SELECT f.id, f.location, f.stockNumber, f.vin, f.totalCarliCost, f.totalCostSubmitted, f.createdDateTime, f.createdBy, f.earliestPaymentDate, f.paymentItems, ARRAY(SELECT * FROM c IN f.lineItems where c.itemState = @lineItemState) as lineItems FROM f WHERE f.stockNumber IN (@allStockNumbers)"
        ).WithParameter("@lineItemState", @lineItemState)
        .WithParameter("@allStockNumbers", allStockNumbers);
}
else
{
    query = new QueryDefinition(
        @"SELECT f.id, f.location, f.stockNumber, f.vin, f.totalCarliCost, f.totalCostSubmitted, f.createdDateTime, f.createdBy, f.earliestPaymentDate, f.paymentItems, f.lineItems FROM f WHERE f.stockNumber IN (@allStockNumbers)"
    ).WithParameter("@allStockNumbers", allStockNumbers);
}
```

I also tried with `ARRAY_CONTAINS` but same thing:

```
var allStockNumbers = string.Join(", ", stockNumbers.Select(x => "\"" + x + "\""));
QueryDefinition query;
if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(filters?.LineItemState))
{
     var lineItemState = "\"" + filters.LineItemState + "\"";
     query = new QueryDefinition(
              "SELECT f.id, f.location, f.stockNumber, f.vin, f.totalCarliCost, f.totalCostSubmitted, f.createdDateTime, f.createdBy, f.earliestPaymentDate, f.paymentItems, ARRAY(SELECT * FROM c IN f.lineItems where c.itemState = @lineItemState) as lineItems FROM f WHERE ARRAY_CONTAINS(@allStockNumbers, f.stockNumber)"
          ).WithParameter("@lineItemState", lineItemState)
          .WithParameter("@allStockNumbers", allStockNumbers);
}
else
{
    query = new QueryDefinition(
        @"SELECT f.id, f.location, f.stockNumber, f.vin, f.totalCarliCost, f.totalCostSubmitted, f.createdDateTime, f.createdBy, f.earliestPaymentDate, f.paymentItems, f.lineItems FROM f WHERE f.stockNumber IN (@allStockNumbers)"
    ).WithParameter("@allStockNumbers", allStockNumbers);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have used `IN` along with `QueryDefinition` object as can be seen below code snippet.

**Below are the steps which I followed for the required output:**

- The first For loop adds query parameters to the query definition object while iterating through the id's array.
- Then using feed iterator we get the result set object in a paginated way. The hasmoreresult set attribute ensures that the retrieval continues till there are any records matching the criteria is available.
- The Cosmos DB query's result set is iterated through using the while loop. The resultSet object is a FeedIterator that enables paginated retrieval of the query results.
- The change I have done is to convert the input to a Json and used the input with LINQ, whereas in your case the LINQ query was used directly.

**Below is the code snippet :**

```cs
    public static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            using (CosmosClient cosmosClient = new CosmosClient(endpointUrl, authKey))
            {
            
            // Getting the CosmosDB container and database name to retrieve records.
                Database database = cosmosClient.GetDatabase(databaseName);

                
                Container container = database.GetContainer(containerName);

                
                string[] ids = { "guid1", "guid2", "guid3" };

                // Query text with parameterized query
                string queryText = "SELECT * FROM c WHERE c.Id IN ({0})";
                string parameterName = "@ids";
                string[] parameterValues = ids.Select((id, index) => $"{parameterName}{index}").ToArray();
                string parameterizedQuery = string.Format(queryText, string.Join(",", parameterValues));

                // Create a QueryDefinition object with the parameterized query
                QueryDefinition query = new QueryDefinition(parameterizedQuery);

                for (int i = 0; i < ids.Length; i++)
                {
                    query = query.WithParameter($"{parameterName}{i}", ids[i]);
                }

                // List to store queried employees
                List<Employee> employees = new List<Employee>();

                using (FeedIterator<Employee> resultSet = container.GetItemQueryIterator<Employee>(query))
                {
                    while (resultSet.HasMoreResults)
                    {
                        FeedResponse<Employee> response = await resultSet.ReadNextAsync();
                        employees.AddRange(response);
                    }
                }

                foreach (Employee employee in employees)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"Id: {employee.Id}, StockNumber: {employee.StockNumber}");

                    
                    Employee newEmployee = new Employee
                    {
                        Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
                        StockNumber = employee.StockNumber
                    };

                    // Writing into CosmosDB item(optional)
                    ItemResponse<Employee> response = await container.CreateItemAsync(newEmployee);
                    Employee savedEmployee = response.Resource;

                    Console.WriteLine($"Saved document with Id: {savedEmployee.Id}");
                }
            }
        }
        catch (CosmosException ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"CosmosException while querying documents: StatusCode={ex.StatusCode}, SubStatusCode={ex.SubStatusCode}, Message={ex.Message}, ActivityId={ex.ActivityId}");
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Press Enter to exit.");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

- Below is the desired result:
  [image]
- The result which I got in the console can also be saved in a Json file in CosmosDb items as in the screenshot below:
  [image]